# Files are not moving to folder in PHP Version 7.2.13

Tags: php, file-upload, server

I am trying to upload files. I am using xampp server. Everything is working perfect in localhost. Files are moving to specific folder. But in server file name is storing in database but not moving to folder. Please check my code

```
     <?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
   $errors= array();
   $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
   $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
   $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

   $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
   }
   }
   ?>
```

```
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Make sure your path is correct and have all the permissions to store the files.

Comment: Permissions? can you explain in detail. I am new to php

Comment: Can you tell me what path is getting stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I gues the destination folder is not well defined. 
Try to make the path absolute to check waht really happens.

```
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "/full/path/to/images/".$file_name);
```

Comment: I am getting error like this (HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections) when trying to use full path

Comment: @Mahmood You don't write to `http://...`! You need to write to a local file path on your server, e.g. something like `/var/www/foo/bar/baz.jpg`. Where to exactly depends on your server.